# How can I create audio from byte array in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, arrays

In android I am using the following line of code to generate sound from byte array

```
byte audioData[];
//.
//fill audioData
//.
final AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            sampleRateInHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, audioData.lenght,
            AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);
audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, audioData.length);
audioTrack.play();
```

How can I achieve this in ios sdk. Is there any equivalent library that generates sound from byteArray?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
NSData *audioData = // take audioData from wherever it is

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil]; // audioPlayer must be a strong property. Do not create it locally

[self.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

make sure to import `AVFoundation` module